Error "Invalid or unexpected" in VSCode when running test
I work on an autotesting project. Stack: TypeScript, NodeJS, Playwright. Tests are launched through a script containing the following configuration:

"npx playwright test --config=basePlaywright.config.ts --headed --project=chromium"

Today, when the script was launched, there was a voltage drop in the power grid. The computer turned off while executing the script. After turning it on, I ran the script again. But now it gives me an error:

Running 0 test using NaN worker   SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected
token
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\here's the way\Input.ts:3:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\here's the way\Login.ts:4:1)


Files are not damaged. I thought it was an issue with VSCode and cleared its cache. But the error did not go away. I think it's something to do with NodeJS or Playwright. But what exactly needs to be checked? Any ideas?

Weird. Maybe reinstall your packages and browsers. Try running the command without VSCode (although it's unlikely VSCode related, I'd think--it's just an editor. The actual command does all the work.). If the issue persists, please share your code as a [mcve].
